# Fixed-digit base64 encode and decode in Python

Tags: python, base64

I'm trying to encode and decode a base64 string. It works fine normally, but if I try to restrict the hash to 6 digits, I get an error on decoding:

```
from base64 import b64encode
from base64 import b64decode

s="something"
```

#### base 64 encode/decode:

```
# Encode:
hash = b64encode(s)
# Decode:
dehash = b64decode(hash)
print dehash
```

(works)

#### 6-digit base 64 encode/decode:

```
# Encode:
hash = b64encode(s)[:6]
# Decode:
dehash = b64decode(hash)
print dehash
```

TypeError: Incorrect padding

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on Mark's answer, I added padding to the 6-digit hash to make it divisible by 4:

```
hash = hash += "=="
```

But now the decode result = "some"

**UPDATE 2**

Wow that was stupid ..

Comment: Why does the updated result surprise you? Are you expecting to get the entire original string somehow magically/fractally encoded to 6 bytes?

Comment: oh man- im an idiot - trying to encode a longer string into a shorter hash... sorry for wasting your guys time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base64 by definition requires padding on the input if it does not decode into an integral number of bytes on the output. Every 4 base64 characters gets turned into 3 bytes. Your input length does not divide evenly by 4, thus there's an error.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) has a good description of the specifics of Base64.